# Need help for turn this form $\neg ((p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow r)$ into DNF

Tags: logic, education, transformation, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

How can I turn this form

1. $\neg( ( p \Rightarrow q ) \Rightarrow r )$

to  disjunctive normal form  and to the disjunctive normal form fully developed ?

I have done the truth table see below

[image: truth table]

I arrived to this form :   $(\neg p \vee q) \wedge r$   but I am not sure if it is correct and if I had developed enough

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be closed, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Answer (score 0):

> I arrived to this form :   $(\neg p \vee q) \wedge r$   but I am not sure if it is correct and if I had developed enough

This is not correct. Hint: $\sf~\neg(A\to B) \equiv A\wedge\neg B~$ by implication negation.